# Transfer postgres database table from one server to another?

Tags: postgresql, vagrant, pgadmin

The pgAdmin gui will not work for the destination database because it is on a vagrant server which is not supported by pgAdmin3.

I would like to copy a database table from one server to another. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: `pg_dump -t table_name >/tmp/tn.sql` + `scp`(or any other way to move file to vargant) + `psql -f`

Comment: I would use `pg_dump`

Comment: Set up a [forwarded port](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html) in Vagrant and use pgAdmin3 or any other tool as if you were in your guest OS

Comment: If you have a network connection between the two servers, you can use a foreign data wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everyone has said in the comment. The canonical and supported way to do this is with `pg_dump` or `pg_dumpall`. Look at the respective man pages. Both are *very* simple to use.